# (React rendering) SetInterval just keeps going faster and unpredictable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timing

I'm trying to implement a simple timer that just counts up continuously every second. I'm using react to render the result. The code is only a few lines and makes sense from what I've been reading. It adds and renders properly for the first 6 seconds; however, it just starts displaying random numbers after the 7th or 8th, OR the timer becomes erroneous and updates every random second. My code is as follows, am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 

  setInterval(()=>{setCount(count + 1)}, 1000)

  return (
    <div className="welcome">
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You have not posted enough code for anybody to help. What does `setCount()` do, for example? How/when/where is `App()` called?

Comment: setCount is the react hook and App() is the react component getting rendered. Sorry if I didn't provide enough info :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some issues, as do the other answers. They can be summarized in three points:

1. If you want to use Interval or Timeout (or any other event listener), you need to do this inside a `useEffect`, so you won't add a new listener in each render.
2. If you use an `useEffect` for it, you'll need to clean up the Interval/Timeout (or any other listener) to avoid memory leaks.
3. We can avoid using the `count` variable inside the dependencies array by using `setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1)`. Citing [React documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/8839059):

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

If you ignore step 3 by using `count` as a hook-dependency, you will create and clean up an Interval in each render - this is unnecessary.
If you decide to just use `setCount(count + 1)` without adding it to the dependency array, you're using hooks wrong, `count` will always have the same value (the initial one).

I added a button to force a re-render in the example below to show that the count keeps going as expected.

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [forced, setForced] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Store the interval id in a const, so you can cleanup later
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(oldCount => oldCount + 1);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => {
      // Since useEffect dependency array is empty, this will be called only on unmount
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);
  
  function forceRerender() {
    setForced(oldForced => oldForced + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count} seconds</p>
      <p>Forced re-renders: {forced}</p>
      <button onClick={forceRerender}>Force a re-render</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

that because it start a new one every time the component rerender
use this instead

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 
  const timer = useRef(null);


useEffect(() => {
  timer.current = setInterval(()=>{setCount(count + 1)}, 1000);
  return () => {
    if(timer.current !== null) clearInterval(timer.current);
  };
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="welcome">
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: For some reason, this code does not work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-black-sx507?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I don't use codesandbox but try this   const timer = useRef<number>();

Comment: This seems like it stops execution once setCount is called.

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval` call should be put inside a `useEffect` hook and cleanup should be done too:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(ref.current);
    };
  }, [count]);

  return <div className="welcome">{count}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: doesn't this restart the `setInterval` everytime `count` increments? Shouldn't the arguments array be empty?

Comment: Yea it seems like, whatever React stuff is going on, the main problem is that the `setInterval()` call is being made over and over again and nothing stops previously-started interval timers.

Comment: I've seen that the other answer does not work, although I do not know why. I've expected it to work better than my one.

Comment: It worked! The problem with what I did was calling setInterval everytime the screen rerendered which caused the erroneous behavious.